# Background Image not covering the whole screen on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem, I want to add a background image for my quote app but when I try to add it the image not covering the whole screen even if I add the 'BoxFit.cover'.
That's what I have on the screen when I load:
[image]

And this is my code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("stuffandmore/Lwolf.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,

          )
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30,right: 30),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Spacer(),
            Image.asset(
              "stuffandmore/quoteimg.png",
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            )
          ],
        )
```

Someone can explain how can I fix that, I will be very greatful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use both `BoxFit.fill` and container width `double.infinte`

```
Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("images/test.jpg"),
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      )),
```